# Повторные запросы axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

axios (post, timeout: 1500) запрос из vue-приложения пытается получить данные с сервера. сервер не доступен (отключил специально).
выводится сообщение об ошибке(Network Error).
после этого запросы на сервер повторяются, причем с каждой попыткой интервалы между запросами сокращаются.

в итоге приходится перезагружать страницу.
друзья, подскажите, как отменить последующее выполнение запросов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 try {
        this.$store.commit('setLoading', false)
        let response = await HTTP.post('auth/checkEmail', { 'email': v })
        console.log(response)
        this.$store.commit('setLoading', false)
        return false
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        this.$store.dispatch('setError', e.message || e)
      }
```

Фрагменты Store

```
   mutations: {
    setError (state, payload) {
      state.error = payload
    },
    clearError (state) {
      state.error = null
    },
    setAppLoading (state, payload) {
      state.appLoading = payload
    },
    setLoading (state, payload) {
      state.loading = payload
    }
  },
  actions: {
    setError ({ commit }, payload) {
      commit('setError', payload)
      setTimeout(() => {
        commit('clearError')
      }, this.getters.errorTimeOut + 700)
    },
    setAppLoading ({ commit }, payload) {
      commit('setAppLoading', payload)
    }
  },
```

Подключение AXIOS

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const HTTP = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api',
  timeout: 1500
})
```

Comment: В этом коде нет того, что вам нужно. Это просто отправка запроса с отловом ошибок.

Comment: тем не менее другого кода нет. HTTP - это обычный экземпляр axios c параметрами baseUrl и timeout.

Comment: Хм, нет. А переотправляет запрос папа римский что ли? Вот у вас есть куски кода, в которых угадывается vuex'овский store - и вполне возможно, что у вас выставление error приводит к выставлению нового статуса с повторной отправкой. В текущем приведённом коде ошибки нет. Как мы вам можем помочь с тем кодом, который мы в глаза не видели - непонятно. У меня в vue + vuex + axios при [выключенном](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/969411/213987) беке на asp.net core повторной переотправки запросов нет.

Comment: Добавил код стора. Есть ли вероятность что запрос уходит по инициативе Google Chrome ?

Comment: У вас в коде стора при поступлении ошибки отрабатывает setError - и через 700 миллисекунд после наступления ошибки ошибка очищается. Тут вот прямо по этому коду нельзя сказать, что это ошибка, но и исключать целиком нельзя. Привести что ли свой кусок аутентификации?

Comment: Я не видел, чтобы чистый хром что-то переотправлял в цикле кроме положенного. Можете открыть firefox и если повторится то же самое поведение - всё-таки это ваш код, а не браузер.

Answer (score 2):

Вроде бы нашел причину. дело было в переключателе в VUE devtools[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прикольно, не знал о таком поведении vue dev. Я видел на en so один баг с этим расширением, но у меня не глючил.

Comment: Проблема пропала после переустановки Vue dev. пока все нормально). Спасибо за помощь!